# Computer and online games RPG/MUD in French

Tags: ressources, jeux

As I recall, I was helped greatly when learning English (I am fluent now) by computer games available at the time, such as King's Quest or Leisure Suit Larry. They required me to read textual descriptions and type in answers and commands. Later, when Internet became available, I spent an ungodly amount of time in the MUDs, which were like textual MMORPGs of the '90s. This was even better, because it was real time communication with real people — all in text.

Is there anything like these games available now in French? I would just google it, except my French googling skills are not what they are in English and I can't find anything comparable. I am currently at A2 level or so.

Comment: This question is barely on-topic, you may want to check if [gaming.SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) is not better suited for your purpose.

Comment: We might have to cut this one in two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, all commercial video games are available in French. If you to buy one just go on fnac.com or amazon.fr:
http://recherche.logiciel-jeux-video.fnac.com/n32823/Jeux-PC/Jeux-de-role-RPG

If you want to get some for free, there are some abadonware RPG on this site:
http://www.abandonware-france.org/ltf_abandon/ltf_listes_jeux.php?rub=4&bonus=&date=&ordre=alpha&search=0

By the way, RPG is JDR (Jeu de rôle) in French.

Answer (score 4):

MUD has no real translations in French, as you can see it on the wikipedia [page](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-user_dungeon). The page also provides some examples.

RPG is commonly known as "Jeu de rôle". It includes board games as well as video games.

#### Off-topic additions:

*you may consider asking about the games themselves on* 
[gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)

Many games features multilingual capabilities and it has really been increasing nowadays with the distribution platforms like Steam, where you can switch language in 3 clicks. It can be very useful to have reading materials (I use to do this with English).

If you're looking for French communities in games, try to look if there is a region setting or ask for guilds. You will probably find one (at least) in every major game which has been release in EU.

Comment: I have accepted the other answer, but thanks for your contrubution, too. Some of the French MUDs you pointed me to seem to be alive and kicking!

Comment: No problem, I'll be happy with the upvotes :P